# Unable to open database file Django/sqlite3

Tags: python, django, sqlite

I get the error

```
    OperationalError: unable to open database file
```

The path leading to my .db file is

```
    ~/Development/Django/django_prac/practice/database
```

Here is my Settings.py

```
    DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', # Add 'postgresql_psycopg2', 'mysql', 'sqlite3' or 'oracle'.
    'NAME': '/Home/Development/Django/django_prac/practice/database/practice.db',                      # Or path to database file if using sqlite3. 
      # The following settings are not used with sqlite3:
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',                      # Empty for localhost through domain sockets or '127.0.0.1' for localhost through TCP.
    'PORT': '',                      # Set to empty string for default.
        }
    }
```

I have also tried

```
    ~/Development/Django/django_prac/practice/database$
```

in my 'NAME' but yet same error occurs

Comment: Did you write `Home` but you wanted `home`?

Comment: First, you should simply check if the file exists, like "ls /Home/Development/Django/django_prac/practice/database/practice.db"

Comment: Have you run ´syncdb´?

Comment: @schneck my Home directory is named "Home" not "home"

Comment: @schneck the file exists

Comment: @lalo i ran python manage.py syncdb and then the error occurs

Comment: ok, what happens if you just try "practice.db" ?

Comment: Are you using Apache? In this case, check https://code.djangoproject.com/wiki/NewbieMistakes#DjangosaysUnabletoOpenDatabaseFilewhenusingSQLite3 - you should anyway check if the user running the project has enough permissions to open the file.

Comment: @lalo simply practice.db worked. Do you know why is that? I'm following a tutorial and it told me to give a path!

Comment: @schneck I'm following the Django website's tutorial and they did not mention anything about Apache so nope!

Comment: I don't know why. but maybe you hace an error in the path. I think django write the file in the manage.py directory as default

Answer (score 3, accepted):

OK, that is my suggestion:

```
DATABASES = {
'default': {
    'ENGINE': 'django.db.backends.sqlite3', 
    'NAME': 'practice.db', # Just the name
    'USER': '',
    'PASSWORD': '',
    'HOST': '',             
    'PORT': '',             
        }
    }
```

I think you maybe have an error in the path, try `pwd` over `/Home/Development/Django/django_prac/practice/database/` directory and copy the output.
Then plus the db name

hope helps